# How to insert NULL in mysql especially INT dataType

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have 80000 recodes that are need to insert into database especially in table: temp(ts, temp)
temp is INT.

The problem is almost 20000 recodes are null, so I am wondering how to insert NULL into DB when dataType is INT.

I tried this:

```
String val = null;

//insert(ts, val) into temp 
String sql = "INSERT INTO temp" + "(val)" + " VALUES" + "('" + val + "')";
Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
count  = st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

unfortunately insert is failure. Print out the exception message:

```
Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'val' at row 1"
```

Wish someone can help me with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use a `PreparedStatement` and use [`setNull(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO temp(val) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
if (/* int value is not null */) {
   st.setInt(1, value);
} else {
   set.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
}
count  = st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Before you told me PrepardStatement, I didn't know it. It is the answer for my question. From API: void setNull(int parameterIndex, int sqlType) throws SQLException :sets the designated parameter to SQL NULL.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Mark Rotteveel's answer, you can also use [PreparedStatement.setObject(int, Object, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int)).

You specify the SQL Type (3rd Parameter), and if the object is null, it inserts a null automatically. It's faster and easier.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO temp(val) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setObject(1, value, Types.INTEGER);
count  = st.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using prepared statements. If you do, you'll find information on how to deal with nulls [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoPreparedStatementSetNullforintvaluecolumn.htm) and elsewhere.

If you're 100% sure your `val` value is clean and won't cause SQL Injection (rare, but possible), then the "built string" approach needs to explicitly use `null` when defining the value:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO temp (val) VALUES (";
if (val == null) {
  sql += "null";
} else {
  sql += val;
}
sql += ")";
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I go a wrong way. If the value is null, it means the record is null, even it has timestamp. So I need to keep the records what are not null.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem.
The codes update as following:

```
String sql= null;
if(val.isEmpty()){
System.out.println(val);
System.out.println("Insert ts: " + ts + " val: null");
sql= "INSERT INTO " + table + "(ts,val,pointId)" + " VALUES" + "(" + "'" + ts + "'" + ", " + "NULL" + " , " + "'" + pointId + "'" + ")";
}
else{
System.out.println("Insert ts: " + ts + " val: " + val);
sql= "INSERT INTO " + table + "(ts,val,pointId)" + " VALUES" + "(" + "'" + ts + "'" + ", " + "'" + val + "'" + ", " + "'" + pointId + "'" + ")";
}

Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();  //create the instances of statement
count = st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Basically, if insert null into database, just do insert into table(val) value(NULL).

Comment: this is a perfectly legitimate solution (tho is can be shortened a bit), too bad it was downvoted without any explanation

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly `CAST` the NULL as an INT

`...VALUES(...CAST(NULL AS INT)`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your are sending "null" in when you should be sending an int.  Perhaps try something like

(val == null ? "" : val)